# Android FirebaseMessaging service... How to send data to another service

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When we receive a Push notification in the FirebaseMessaging service class the onMessageReceived handler is called. We have another main Background service in the app. How do we send the data from the Push notification to this other service.

```
public class PushMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService {

      @Override
      public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {

           Map<String, String> data = message.getData();
          // Call method in Main Service
          // How to do this?

      }
 }
```

Comment: You can send data on that background service using broad cast receiver. when ever you get data in onMessage then you need to call custom Broad cast and Define receiver in that services

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42607569/1563038

Comment: @MehulTank  OK, thanks will do this